# Java Package Applet Confusion

Tags: java, applet

So I made my first simple program which is a applet that displays a word with color, font, etc. I compiled the code, but it gave me this error message: "cannot find simbol" twice! Once on line 1 pointing at the dot between awt and Applet, and on line 6 pointing at Applet. Any help would be fantastic!!!

```
import java.awt.Applet; ///error here
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;

public class AppletDemo extends Applet ///and here
{
public void paint( Graphics screen )
{
    Font f = new Font( "TimesRoman", Font.ITALIC, 30 );
    screen.setFont( f );
    screen.setColor( new Color(200, 50, 20));
    screen.drawString( "I'm a Java Applet!!!", 50, 50 );
}
}
```

Comment: how do you compile your code ?

Comment: What IDE and compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) mentions the import at the top.  Change:

```
import java.awt.Applet;
```

to:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
```